# Pig throwing incompatible type error

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, bigdata

I am using the following code to generate sessionId in pig by using sessionize UDF in datafu.

```
 SET       mapred.min.split.size 1073741824   
SET       mapred.job.queue.name 'marathon'
 SET       mapred.output.compress true;
--SET       avro.output.codec snappy;
--SET       pig.maxCombinedSplitSize 536870912;



page_view_pre = LOAD '/data/tracking/PageViewEvent/' USING LiAvroStorage('date.range','start.date=20150226;end.date=20150226;error.on.missing=true');  -----logic is currently for 2015-02-26,will later replace them with date parameters
p_key = LOAD '/projects/dwh/dwh_dim/dim_page_key/#LATEST' USING LiAvroStorage();


page_view_pre = FILTER page_view_pre  BY (requestHeader.userAgent != 'CRAWLER' and requestHeader.browserId != 'CRAWLER') and NOT IsTestMemberId(header.memberId);


page_view_pre = FOREACH page_view_pre GENERATE 
            (int)   (header.memberId <0 ? -9 : header.memberId )           as member_sk,
            (chararray)  requestHeader.browserId                               as browserId,
    --(chararray)       requestHeader.sessionId                                    as sessionId,
(chararray)         UnixToISO(header.time)                                     as pageViewTime,
            header.time                                                    as pv_time,
    (chararray) requestHeader.path                                 as path,
    (chararray)     requestHeader.referer                                  as referer,
    (chararray)  epochToFormat(header.time, 'yyyyMMdd', 'America/Los_Angeles') as tracking_date,
(chararray)         requestHeader.pageKey                                      as pageKey,
    (chararray)        SUBSTRING(requestHeader.trackingCode, 0, 500)           as trackingCode,  
        FLATTEN(botLookup(requestHeader.userAgent, requestHeader.browserId))   as (is_crawler, crawler_type),
    (int)   totalTime                                                                  as totalTime,
    ((int) totalTime < 20 ? 1 :0)                                                    as bounce_flag;    

page_view_pre = FILTER page_view_pre BY is_crawler == 'N' ;

p_key = FILTER p_key By is_aggregate ==1;

page_view_agg = JOIN page_view_pre by pageKey ,p_key by page_key;

page_view_agg = FOREACH page_view_agg GENERATE
                 (chararray)page_view_pre::member_sk as member_sk,
                 (chararray)page_view_pre::browserId as browserId,
                --page_view_pre::sessionId as sessionId,
                (chararray)page_view_pre::pageViewTime as pageViewTime,
                (long)page_view_pre::pv_time as pv_time,
                (chararray)page_view_pre::tracking_date as tracking_date,
                (chararray)page_view_pre::path as path,
                (chararray)page_view_pre::referer as referer,
                (chararray)page_view_pre::pageKey as pageKey,
                (int)p_key::page_key_sk as page_key_sk,
                (chararray)page_view_pre::trackingCode as trackingCode,
                (int)page_view_pre::totalTime as totalTime,
                (int)page_view_pre::bounce_flag as bounce_flag;

page_view_agg = FILTER page_view_agg By (member_sk is NOT null) OR (browserId IS NOT NULL) ;        

pvs_by_member_browser_pair = GROUP page_view_agg BY (member_sk,browserId);



***session_groups = FOREACH pvs_by_member_browser_pair {
                                visits = ORDER page_view_agg BY pv_time;
                                GENERATE FLATTEN(Sessionize(visits)) AS (
                                pageViewTime,member_sk, pv_time,tracking_date, pageKey,page_key_sk,browserId,referer ,path, trackingCode,totalTime, sessionId
                                                                        );
                                                    }***
```

The bolded part is giving me the following error  :

> ERROR 1031: Incompatable schema: left is "pageViewTime:NULL,member_sk:NULL,pv_time:NULL,tracking_date:NULL,pageKey:NULL,page_key_sk:NULL,browserId:NULL,referer:NULL,path:NULL,trackingCode:NULL,totalTime:NULL,sessionId:NULL", right is "datafu.pig.sessions.sessionize_visits_43::member_sk:chararray,datafu.pig.sessions.sessionize_visits_43::browserId:chararray,datafu.pig.sessions.sessionize_visits_43::pageViewTime:chararray,datafu.pig.sessions.sessionize_visits_43::pv_time:long,datafu.pig.sessions.sessionize_visits_43::tracking_date:chararray,datafu.pig.sessions.sessionize_visits_43::path:chararray,datafu.pig.sessions.sessionize_visits_43::referer:chararray,datafu.pig.sessions.sessionize_visits_43::pageKey:chararray,datafu.pig.sessions.sessionize_visits_43::page_key_sk:int,datafu.pig.sessions.sessionize_visits_43::trackingCode:chararray,datafu.pig.sessions.sessionize_visits_43::totalTime:int,datafu.pig.sessions.sessionize_visits_43::bounce_flag:int,datafu.pig.sessions.sessionize_visits_43::session_id:chararray"

I thought initially this had to do with null member or browser id's.I filtered for them too, still the error is persisting.I have been stuck here for hours.Would really appreciate some pointers or solution to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classical case of Schema mismatch:

```
page_view_pre = LOAD '/data/tracking/PageViewEvent/' USING LiAvroStorage('date.range','start.date=20150226;end.date=20150226;error.on.missing=true');  -----logic is currently for 2015-02-26,will later replace them with date parameters
```

Just have `illustrate page_view_pre` after this line to figure out the schema.